# Starting Resque at boot / Passenger restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, resque

My environment: Rails 3.2.x with RVM, Passenger, Apache on Linux (Ubuntu), I am not using Capistrano and not intending to do so for the time being.

I have integrated Resque into my Rails application and all works well when manually starting resque with

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production environment resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

Next step is to have Resque startup (restart) automatically when Passenger starts (restarts).

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) for this issue?

Foreman is a procfile-based tool to manage multi-process rails apps.

A simple intro can be seen at [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman). An example may look like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
solr: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
resque: rake RAILS_ENV=production environment resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

Comment: I am trying to keep my production server as lean as possible, avoiding all dependencies as much as I can. Nevertheless, at first glance seems to look worthwhile a second look. Question though, how do you start foreman at system startup or integrate it into Passenger?

Comment: For example via an upstart export that you can create via capistrano deploy and then use at startup.

Comment: namespace :foreman do
  task :export, :roles => :db do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec foreman export upstart /etc/init -u #{user} -a #{application} -f Procfile.#{rails_env}"
  end

  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "restart #{application} || start #{application}"
  end
end

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but do I want foreman to start the `rails server`? Shouldn't that be left to passenger?

Comment: @PrathanThananart: it depends on which kind of application-server you are using and off course in which environment you are running. The example comes from the procfile for development. 
The idea of foreman is to have a process to rule them all - so choose however you want, but choose wisely.

Comment: This answer does not integrate with Passenger as requested in the question.

Comment: Why did you downvote the answer? In case of using passenger, you could  use the following command: `web: touch tmp/restart.txt`